# Databricks init script is failing to install packages but reporting as "Succeeded" regardless?

Tags: python, package, cluster-computing, azure-databricks, init

I have been attempting to setup 'init scripts' on databricks, so I can install all of my python libraries and keep the environment controlled.

Tried yesterday using the init script pictured below:

```
dbutils.fs.put("/DA/Temp/ClusterTest/python_requirements_test2.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
pip install pyodbc==4.0.32
pip install zeep==4.1.0
""", True)
```

This was successful!

But after trialling some other techinques and coming back to this method, the init script is no longer installing any of the libraries..

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Below is the 'Event Log' note about the init script, showing "Status: SUCCEEDED" even though no libraries are actually installed:
[image: "Status: SUCCEEDED" even though no libraries are actually installed]

Comment: **Side note:**
After running ```pipdeptree```, the packages are appearing, the problem seems to be the databricks cluster UI not showing these packages.

Answer (score 1):

After a conversation with Databricks support team, it is an intended functionality of their Clusters UI to **NOT** show packages installed via init script in the UI. These packages are installed however and this does not indicate that the packages arent installed.

I have asked the support team to update their documentation on this, as it was not clear that this was an intended behaviour.

Comment: Does it still appear with an ```%sh pip freeze```  or ```%sh pip list```command ?

Answer (score -1):

> When you install a library on a cluster, a notebook already attached
> to that cluster will not immediately see the new library. You must
> first detach and then reattach the notebook to the cluster.

To [View the libraries installed on a cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/cluster-libraries#view-the-libraries-installed-on-a-cluster):

- Click compute icon Compute in the sidebar.
- Click the cluster name.
- Click the Libraries tab. For each library, the tab displays the name and version, type, install status, and, if uploaded, the source file.

Comment: The problem is the libraries are NOT showing up on libraries tab in Compute, but are showing up on the notebook when running ```pipdeptree``` to see installed packages and the dependencies.

The libraries are not installed on a notebook scope as if I open a new notebook and inistall and run pipdeptree, they still appear.